# How to troubleshoot an installed program that does not run in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, troubleshooting

I cannot manage to run a program.exe in a PC with Windows 10. The program needs a USB key to run. 
The key and the program work fine on *any* other PC that I have tried, so they are OK. But in the particular PC that I need it to run, it appears for a few seconds on the list of running processes in the Task Manager but then disappears.

When I used Process Explorer, I saw that `werFault.exe` is launched
immediately after the program stops running. 
Event Viewer logs a faulting module: `mfc140.dll`.

I reset the PC to factory settings with Windows 10 Pro version 1909 (Nov 2019). The USB key appears as "HID Dongle" on Devices list, as it also appears on all the other PCs I tried.

The laptop where it does not to run is a ThinkPad T490, Model: 20N2, with an i7-8565U CPU. I tried on another Thinkpad T470 20HF with an i7-7500U CPU, which is a generation older and the program ran here well.

I created a simple MFC application to make use of the `mfc140.dll` library and it works ok, so the libray by itself is not the problem. Something in program.exe when calling `mfc140.dll` makes it break, but only on the ThinkPad T490, in all  PCs I tried it works ok. The TP T490 has the newest cpu of all PCs tried. This is really puzzling and what else I could try?

Comment: Look into Event Viewer - Windows Logs - Application to see if anything is registered therein giving you some clues.

Comment: @patkim You beat me to it by a few seconds. Eventlog is the first place to look.

Comment: Is Any Other PC where it runs also having Windows 10? Also try Compatibility Troubleshooter and see if it helps in anyway.

Comment: If you question is closed, please do not resubmit the exact same question, instead [edit] the question.  I recognize this question, which means you deleted the original question, likely because it was closed.

Comment: Run Process Monitor while reproducing.  The exit code of the process might give some idea but comparing the events in Process Monitor against a working computer is probably the best thing at this point.  Initially if you filter to the modules being loaded by the process to make the comparison easier.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the suggestions. Ramhound this is my first time ever asking a question in this forum. HelpingHand I used Process Explorer and saw werFault.exe is launched immediately after the program stops running. @patkim and Tonny, in Event Viewer logs a faulting module: mfc140.dll. I will try to see online what to do with this how to replace it...

Comment: Try creating a new user (which will create its own profile files) and try running the same program when logged in as that new user and see if it crashes again. Just one more small check.

Comment: @patkim Done this, the same situation. I have tried installing in many other PCs and the program runs well, maybe my PC is too new?
It's a Lenovo ThinkPad T490, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz, RAM 16.0 GB, System: 64-bit OS, x64-based processor, Edition: Windows 10 Pro, Version: 21H1, Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0

I think the question I need to solve now becomes: How to troubleshoot the faulting module: mfc140.dll to run in the PC above. I mean how can I make a simple application that uses this library and see where and how it fails in this PC?